# multi admin in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

There is a project of Hotels, and for each hotel there is one admin.

What I have done:
In **Usertype** table different types of Users like chef,managers,hotel

If user type is hotel means it is the admin of that hotel.
Now for each and every CRUD and other functionalities I get hotel id like this
`$hotel_id = \Auth::user()->hotel_id;`
and checked this `hotel_id` in each query(`like get user, save user, get invoice,set invoice,check food etc`).
Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a correct way to check if a user is hotel's admin. But it's better to use policies for that:

```
public function update(User $user, Hotel $hotel)
{
    return $user->id === $hotel->user_id;
}
```

> Policies are classes that organize authorization logic around a particular model or resource.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#generating-policies

Comment: Using middleware I check if usertype is hotel then I logged that user as admin of that hotel(hotel id in user table)
But my question is : 
In all the functions of CRUD and other functionalities(book hotel,profile,departments ) I need to  fetch $hotel_id = \Auth::user()->hotel_id; for every (db query)function of controller to verify that this belongs to the same hotel which is logged in.

Comment: As I said, you shouldn't do it in a controller, use policy classes for that. In policy, you can check if authenticated user's `hotel_id` equals Hotel ID. Look at an example in updated answer.